# "Develop a feel for something" or "develop the feel for something"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Could you tell if I have to use *"a"* or *"the"* before *feel* in the following sentences?

> If you don't use the word correctly, don't be frustrated as you will develop **a/the** feel for when to use it.

I feel that both articles can be used there without any difference in meaning. If I am wrong, I would like to know why I can use one, but not the other.

Comment: Both seem fine. "The" seems to be more specific on the type of feel. "A feel" seems more subjective and varied according to the person.

Comment: I can't explain why, but the indefinite article *feels* more natural to me. "You will develop ***a*** feel for it."

Comment: Both versions are syntactically fine, but [***the indefinite article is far more common.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=develop+the+feel+for%2Cdevelop+a+feel+for%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdevelop%20the%20feel%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevelop%20a%20feel%20for%3B%2Cc0) Arguably if the speaker is *familiar* with "the feel" (and/or expects his audience to also be familiar with at least the *concept* of the ***particular aptitude*** being referenced), he might prefer the definite article. But really, that's just clutching at straws.